# How do I increase number of concurrent requests HttpSys will process?

Tags: c#, .net, httpsys

We have a bunch of services which run with selfhosted http-listener using HttpSys.

From what we can see, the HttpSys will only start 28 concurrent requests (at least on our developer workstations with 4 cores). How do we increase that?

We tried adjusting MaxAccepts, but it does not appear to have any effect

```
_host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseHttpSys(options =>
    {
        options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
        options.MaxConnections = -1;
        options.MaxAccepts = 200;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has answered me on this one. There are no limits on concurrent requests. At least no other limit than the .net ThreadPool.

MaxAccepts is how many threads are pulling work of the request-queue, and seding the requests to the Threadpool for processing

Microsofts full response [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13575)